# How to say 'learn by ear' in German?

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

In English we say someone can ***learn by ear*** when speaking of music or language.

Is there a German equivalent?

Comment: Deutsch nur vom Hören lernen. Aber weit kommt man damit nicht.

Answer (score 8):

The equivalent phrase for "by ear" is usually *nach [dem] Gehör* (the article is optional and does not change the meaning), which you can use with *spielen* (e.g., *Er spielt Musik nach [dem] Gehör*) or *lernen* (e.g., *Ich lerne nach [dem] Gehör*) and so forth.

Comment: Bist Du sicher, dass es nicht "durch Zuhören" oder "vom Zuhören" bedeutet? Geht es nur um Aussprache (sofern es nicht um Musik geht)?